# Using a local instance of NoSql database to store user settings (Windows desktop)

Tags: c#, windows, nosql

I want to store user settings (under the users profile) and I wanting to avoid having to write an API layer to read/write settings to file(s) and was considering using a NpSQL DB.

Is there a client side NoSQL DB available which does not require an install/configuration before use, and can be created/initialised from a file path first time?

Comment: You may try this: http://www.eztools-software.com/tools/filedb/. It is available on NuGet.

Comment: You do know that [Application Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-application-settings-dotnet?view=vs-2019) can be stored per user?

Comment: Just curious: if Application Settings is not for you, why do want explicitly "NoSQL"? My first thought would have been "SQLite"...

Comment: no reason not to use Application Settings, forgotten about this to be honest. Had thought about SqlLite as well, just looking around for experienced views. I do know SO does n't like opinionated answers...

Answer (score 0):

You could check out [LiteDB](https://www.litedb.org/).

It's a standalone, serverless database delivered in a single small DLL (< 450kb) and fully written in managed code.

You could install it into your app using [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LiteDB):

```
>Install-Package LiteDB
```

I've used it for similar purposes myself.